# Choosing language and design for a cross platform OpenGL ES 2.0+ engine - iOS & Android

Tags: android, c++, ios, c, opengl-es

I'm starting to code something in `OpenGL ES 2.0+` and `EGL` for `Android`, now to achieve the maximum compatibility across multiple devices, i would like to ask:

- what language i'm supposed to pick, `C`or `C++` ? (this question is based on the fact that i do not know `Xcode` very well and i don't know how good it's with `C` or `C++`)
- EGL is mandatory for native app under Android, but what about iOS or other platforms ?
- there are `OpenGL ES 2.0` functions that are not considered as a core part of that profile ? I mean i can have some functions for `OpenGL ES 2.0` for `Android` that are a risk for portability and will not work under `iOS` for example ?
- i can write a complete app for `iOS` in `C` or `C++` without wrappers or third party libraries ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Apple's compiler supports: `C++`, `C` and `objective C`, although ties to all their `API's` are designed mostly for `Obj C`, you can still use `C++` or `C` for them, `OpenGL ES 2.0` is fully supported by both `iOS`, and `Android`. If you wanted to use iOS as your main platform (Which as a business decision makes the most sense), than it's possible to obtain plugins for android's `NDK` compiler to do `objective c`.

This being said, I'd use `C++`, as you'd get cross compatibility with not only `Android` and `iOS`, but `MAC OS, Linux, Windows, BSD, BeOS, Haiku` and so on. `Xcode` in my opinion is a great `IDE`, interface builder is great, in the latest release it's free from any bugs (Haven't had a crash at all), it's also a good platform for testing your apps. I'm no android expert (Don't consider it to be worth developing for, unless I was on to an angry birds kind of game) but I know it favors `Java` (Correct me if I'm wrong the standard `SDK` does this), so you'd have to use `NDK` to get `C++/C` functionality. Do some research of your own, as all the information you're after isn't hard to come by with a quick google search.

Comment: This is a mix between individual ideas and incomplete informations. Also thanks to Angry Birds Rovio is now a real software house and on the iOS market i can't even verify how much i sell, it's probably the opposite compared to the idea of business. I need a focus on the languages and technologies.

Comment: I threw in a bit of what I know, really the last sentence sums up what you should being doing: research. It seems people in this field want specialized help to suit their situation, in reality it involves research and some imagination(Researching a topic and than improvising on the various things you find to get you're final product), if you can't research or work out things for yourself than this probably isn't the thing for you.

Comment: Also, iOS is the best for business, look at the statistics, look at how clean and easy to use there API's are. And you can verify how much you've sold, whoever told you different knows nothing. I'm signed on to the apple developers program so I know this.